# How to adjust the parameters to achieve which MV has more action?

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I use Q1 and Q2 to control T1, so as to realize the simulation scenario of multi-controls. I want to adjust the parameters to achieve which MV has more action, as shown in the figure. I found that I couldn’t achieve the effect I wanted by adjusting the cost of the MV, can anyone give me some suggestions? thanks!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import tclab
from tclab import labtime
from tclab import TCLabModel
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import json

class tclab_heaterpipe():
    delay_q1_step = 10
    delay_q2_step = 10
    q1_buffer = [0] * delay_q1_step
    q2_buffer = [0] * delay_q2_step
    m = TCLabModel()

    def __init__(self, d1, d2, model):
        if d1 >= 1 and d2 >= 1:
            self.delay_q1_step = int(d1)
            self.delay_q2_step = int(d2)
            self.q1_buffer = [0] * self.delay_q1_step
            self.q2_buffer = [0] * self.delay_q2_step
            self.m = model
        else:
            self.delay_q1_step = 0
            self.delay_q2_step = 0

    def Q1_delay(self, q1):
        if self.delay_q1_step == 0:
            self.m.Q1(q1)
        self.q1_buffer.insert(0, q1)
        self.m.Q1(self.q1_buffer.pop())

    def Q2_delay(self, q2):
        if self.delay_q2_step == 0:
            self.m.Q1(q2)
        self.q2_buffer.insert(0, q2)
        self.m.Q2(self.q2_buffer.pop())

# Connect to Arduino
connected = False
theta = 1
theta2 = 1
T = tclab.setup(connected)
a = T()
tclab_delay = tclab_heaterpipe(theta, theta2, a)
# Turn LED on
print('LED On')
a.LED(100)

# Run time in minutes
run_time = 80.0
# Number of cycles
loops = int(60.0 * run_time)

#########################################################
# Initialize Model
#########################################################
# use remote=True for MacOS
m = GEKKO(name='tclab-mpc', remote=False)

m.time = np.linspace(0, 400, 41)
step = 10
# Temperature (K)
t1sp = 45.0
T1 = np.ones(int(loops / step) + 1) * a.T1  # temperature (degC)
Tsp1 = np.ones(int(loops / step) + 1) * t1sp  # set point (degC)
# heater values
Q1s = np.ones(int(loops / step) + 1) * 0.0
Q2s = np.ones(int(loops / step) + 1) * 0.0

# Parameters
Q1_ss = m.Param(value=0)
TC1_ss = m.Param(value=a.T1)
Q2_ss = m.Param(value=0)
Kp1 = m.Param(value=0.8)
tau1 = m.Param(value=160.0)
Kp2 = m.Param(value=0.1)
tau2 = m.Param(value=160.0)

# Manipulated variable
Q1 = m.MV(value=0, name='q1')
Q1.STATUS = 1  # use to control temperature
Q1.FSTATUS = 0  # no feedback measurement
Q1.LOWER = 0.0
Q1.UPPER = 100.0
Q1.DMAX = 50.0
Q1.DCOST = 1.0
# Q1.COST = 0.1

Q2 = m.MV(value=0, name='q2')
Q2.STATUS = 1  # use to control temperature
Q2.FSTATUS = 0  # no feedback measurement
Q2.LOWER = 0.0
Q2.UPPER = 100.0
Q2.DCOST = 1.0
# Q2.COST = 1.0

# Controlled variable
TC1 = m.CV(value=a.T1, name='tc1')
TC1.STATUS = 1  # minimize error with setpoint range
TC1.FSTATUS = 1  # receive measurement
TC1.TR_INIT = 2  # reference trajectory
TC1.WSPHI = 20
TC1.WSPLO = 20
TC1.TAU = 40  # time constant for response
# TC1.COST = 1

Q1d = m.Var()
m.delay(Q1, Q1d, theta)
Q2d = m.Var()
m.delay(Q2, Q2d, theta2)
# Equation
m.Equation(tau1 * TC1.dt() + (TC1 - TC1_ss) == Kp1 * (Q1d - Q1_ss))
m.Equation(tau2 * TC1.dt() + (TC1 - TC1_ss) == Kp2 * (Q2d - Q2_ss))

# Global Options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 3  # Objective type
m.options.NODES = 2  # Collocation nodes
m.options.MAX_TIME = 10
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # 1=APOPT, 3=IPOPT
##################################################################

# Create plot
plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.show()

# Main Loop
a.Q1(0)
a.Q2(0)
Q2s[0:] = 0
start_time = time.time()

tm = np.zeros(int(loops / step) + 1)
j = 0

try:
    time_start = time.time()
    labtime_start = labtime.time()
    if (not connected):
        labtime.set_rate(10)
    for i in tclab.clock(loops, adaptive=False):
        i = int(i)
        if (i == 0):
            continue
        print("-----------------------")
        t_real = time.time() - time_start
        t_lab = labtime.time() - labtime_start
        print("real time = {0:4.1f}    lab time = {1:4.1f}    m.time = {1:4.1f}".format(t_real, t_lab, m.time))
        if (i % step != 0):
            continue
        j = i / step
        j = int(j)
        print(j)
        T1[j] = a.T1
        tm[j] = i
        ###############################
        ### MPC CONTROLLER          ###
        ###############################
        TC1.MEAS = T1[j]
        print("T1 meas:{0:4.1f} ".format(a.T1))
        # input setpoint with deadband +/- DT
        DT = 0.5
        TC1.SPHI = Tsp1[j] + DT
        TC1.SPLO = Tsp1[j] - DT

        try:
            # stop model time to solve MPC in cast the solver takes too much time
            if (not connected):
                labtime.stop()
            m.solve(disp=False)
            # start model time
            if (not connected):
                labtime.start()
        except Exception as e:
            if (not connected):
                if (not labtime.running):
                    labtime.start()
            print("sovle's exception:")
            print(e)
            if (j != 0):
                Q1s[j] = Q1s[j - 1]
                Q2s[j] = Q2s[j - 1]
            continue
        # test for successful solution
        if (m.options.APPSTATUS == 1):
            # retrieve the first Q value
            tclab_delay.Q1_delay(Q1.NEWVAL)
            tclab_delay.Q2_delay(Q2.NEWVAL)
            Q1s[j:] = np.ones(len(Q1s) - j) * Q1.NEWVAL
            Q2s[j:] = np.ones(len(Q2s) - j) * Q2.NEWVAL
            # a.Q1(Q1.NEWVAL)
            # a.Q2(Q2.NEWVAL)
            print("Q1 applied with delay: {0:4.1f}  ".format(Q1.NEWVAL))
            print("Q2 applied with delay: {0:4.1f}  ".format(Q2.NEWVAL))
            with open(m.path + '//results.json') as f:
                results = json.load(f)
        else:
            # not successful, set heater to zero
            Q1s[j] = Q1s[j - 1]
            Q2s[j] = Q2s[j - 1]
            print("APPSTATUS is not 1,set Q to 0")

        if (not connected):
            labtime.stop()
        # Plot
        try:
            plt.clf()
            ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
            ax.grid()
            plt.plot(tm[0:j], T1[0:j], 'ro', markersize=3, label=r'$T_1$')
            plt.plot(tm[0:j], Tsp1[0:j], 'r-', markersize=3, label=r'$T_1 Setpoint$')

            plt.plot(tm[j] + m.time, results['tc1.bcv'], 'r-.', markersize=1, \
                     label=r'$T_1$ predicted', linewidth=1)

            plt.ylabel('Temperature (degC)')
            plt.legend(loc='best')
            ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
            ax.grid()
            plt.plot(tm[0:j], Q1s[0:j], 'r-', linewidth=3, label=r'$Q_1$')
            plt.plot(tm[0:j], Q2s[0:j], 'b-', linewidth=3, label=r'$Q_2$')
            plt.plot(tm[j] + m.time, Q1.value, 'r-.', \
                     label=r'$Q_1$ plan', linewidth=1)
            plt.plot(tm[j] + m.time, Q2.value, 'b-.', \
                     label=r'$Q_2$ plan', linewidth=1)
            plt.ylabel('Heaters')
            plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
            plt.legend(loc='best')
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.05)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

        if (not connected):
            labtime.start()

    # Turn off heaters
    a.Q1(0)
    a.Q2(0)
    print('Shutting down')
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    a.close()

# Allow user to end loop with Ctrl-C
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Disconnect from Arduino
    a.Q1(0)
    a.Q2(0)
    print('Shutting down')
    a.close()

# Make sure serial connection still closes when there's an error
except:
    # Disconnect from Arduino
    a.Q1(0)
    a.Q2(0)
    print('Error: Shutting down')
    a.close()
    raise
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a many ways to preferentially select one MV over another with additional resources on the course website with [Control Objectives](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective) and [Control Tuning](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning).

- [COST](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionCost) (minimize or maximize use of MV)
- [DCOST](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionDcost) (change penalty)
- [DMAX](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionDmax) (move change constraint)
- [TIER](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionTier) (for strong decoupling)

For this particular problem, it appears that the two MVs (Manipulated Variables) Q1 and Q2 values should be a ratio and there is only one CV (Controlled Variable). An easy way to accomplish this is to add another equation such as:

```py
m.Equation(Q2==1.29*Q1)
```

This consumes a degree a freedom with the equation so that there is effectively only one MV. If the STATUS is off then this could lead to a solver error (Infeasible solution) so you may want to change one of the MVs to a `m.Var()` type (such as Q2) if this is a problem.